# Duplication and last entry is not present

Tags: php

I have this array

**$g=("RathiB36E8310"=>"10","JindalB36E8320"=>"20","RathiB36E8310"=>"5")**

If same combination of `$pr_vendor$brand$category` exists then i add the `$cart_item['quantity']` to it and hence it gets updated.
But my last entry is not getting updated and duplicate values exist inspite of not in array condition.What is that i am doing wrong

```
 $g = array("$pr_vendor$brand$category" => $cart_item['quantity']);
        $keyExists;
        foreach ($wer as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == "$pr_vendor$brand$category") {
                $wer["$pr_vendor$brand$category"]+=$cart_item['quantity'];
                $keyExists = "true";
            }
        }
        if (!$keyExists == "true") {
            $wer[] = $g;
    }
```

**OUTPUT (Expected)**

$wer=array("RathiB36E8310"=>"15","JindalB36E8320"=>"20")

Comment: You can't have arrays with duplicated keys!

Comment: it was for example i have updated correct now @M.I.

Comment: You still have duplicate keys in the $g array "RathiB36E8310", you can't have that.

Comment: variables $pr_vendor=Rathi,$brand=B36E83,$category=10 @Rishi

Comment: i am using that for example when dupliacte key arise it should not be stored in array rather only value should be updated @M.I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$wer = array();
    array_key_exists("$pr_vendor$brand$category",$wer) ? $wer["$pr_vendor$brand$category"] += $cart_item['quantity'] : $wer["$pr_vendor$brand$category"] = $cart_item['quantity'];
```

---

And this would be your code corrected:

```
$wer = array();
$keyExists = false;
foreach ($wer as $key => $value) {
   if ($key == "$pr_vendor$brand$category") {
      $wer["$pr_vendor$brand$category"]+=$cart_item['quantity'];
      $keyExists = true;
   }
}
if ($keyExists !== true) {
   $wer["$pr_vendor$brand$category"] = $cart_item['quantity'];
}
```

You cannot ever use !$keyExists == 'true':
1. You can simply use !== or != to compare 
2. Also you have have set a string to $keyExists you can't negate a string   !'true' doesn't work that way
3. Try to use Boolean's that's the whole reason they exists (true, false)
4. for Boolean's set a default value

Comment: `$wer[] = $g` adds an array in `$wer` instead of adding an new entry

Comment: that's one...but you would have seen that if u have used comparative statements good. (!$keyExists == "true") can you explain this?

Answer (score 2):

Some improvements to your code :

- Use PHP function `array_key_exists()` to check if the value is present in the array, instead of iterating over the whole array.
- Instead of `$wer[] = $g` you should use concatenate `$g` to `$wer`. Here you had an array in the array, instead of just adding the new item and its quantity. I would use `array_merge($g, $wer)`.